# center button inside a fluid div

Tags: html, css

I am having a tricky(at least for me) problem with a div which is a flip card done purely in css. The front of the card shows an image and the back has a different image and a button. The problem is due to the fluid design I had to set the padding. Which places all of the text below the div

```css
.card {
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 600px;
    }

    .card__front,
    .card__back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .card__front,
    .card__back {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s;
      transition: transform 0.7s;
    }

    .card__front {
      background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/mmu649.jpg");
      padding-top: 56.25%;
      background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .card__back {
      background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/mmu649.jpg");
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      padding-top: 56.25%;
      background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .card.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    .card.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
      transform: rotateY(0);
    }

    .card__text {
      width: auto;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      margin-top: -32%;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #000000;
      text-indent: 0;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 21px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      height: 69px;
      line-height: 69px;
      width: 200px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .button:hover {
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color- stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #000000));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000');
      background-color: #000000;
    }

    .button:active {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="card effect__hover">
  <div class="card__front">
    <div class="card__text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <div class="card__text"> <a href="http://google.co.uk" class="button">see more</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /card -->
```

Here is the preview of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/j29mvoLm/

All I am trying to get is to center the same button in every card like div.
Is it possible to do it without using negative margin?

Answer (score 0):

This should do you justice:

```
.element {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

or

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: did not work, I have placed the first code inside my card__text element and the button ended up underneath the image

Comment: Play with the positioning. Instead of top 50%, you could use like 5% or something. It is all relative to the CSS you already have, so that method doesn't necessarily apply universally. I know you are looking for a way to just center it with CSS, and the methods I gave you are the way (one of them, at least). Your custom CSS may be overwriting things, thus causing it to appear at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. See snippet. This answer uses nested relative and absolute positioned elements and also utilized `box-sizing:border-box;` and padding to maintain aspect ratio.

If you need to to set a max-width, add another wrapper element around your card and set the `max-width` on that element.

```css
.card-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.card {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 28.125% 50%; /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.card__front, .card__back {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.card__front, .card__back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s;
          transition: transform 0.7s;
}

.card__front {
    background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/mmu649.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.card__back {
    background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/mmu649.jpg");
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    
    
}
.card.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
}
.card__text {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 69px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 69px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

.button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #000000) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #000000 5%, #000000 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000');
    background-color:#000000;
}

.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
<div class="card effect__hover">
  <div class="card__front">
    <div class="card__text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card__back">
    <div class="card__text"> <a href="http://google.co.uk" class="button">see more</a> </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /card -->
</div>
```